# Fast way of converting a class + child classes into JSON format?

Tags: c#, json

I have a class, let's call it `Person`, which holds a number of details about a person, and has number of properties and child classes that represent these details.

For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string StreetName { get; set;}
    public string Town { get; set;}
    public string City { get; set;}
    public string Postcode { get; set;}
}
```

I need to transform this data into a JSON file of a pre-determined and fixed structure. The format of this file is as follows:

```
{
  "People": [
    {
      "PersonId": "1",
      "PersonFields": [
        {
          "Description": "string",
          "Value": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON file above holds an array, the elements of which are populated using the details held within a `Person` object, each person has an Id, and then the details of each e.g. `FirstName`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, `StreetName`, `Town`, `City` and `Postcode` are all stored as separate elements within the `PersonFields` array, where the `Description` is the property name, and the `Value` is the value held inside that property.

So essentially I need to be able to convert the `Person` object into the below:

```
{
  "People": [
    {
      "PersonId": "1",
      "PersonFields": [
        {
          "Description": "FirstName",
          "Value": "John"
        },
        {
          "Description": "LastName",
          "Value": "Smith"
        },
        {
          "Description": "PhoneNumber",
          "Value": "0123456789"
        },
        {
          "Description": "StreetName",
          "Value": "Street"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Town",
          "Value": "Town"
        },
        {
          "Description": "City",
          "Value": "City"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Postcode",
          "Value": "AB1 2CD"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can obviously do this manually, instantiating each `PersonFields` element and setting the description and value, then populating the array with them. However this seems like a very long winded and unnecessary way to go about this problem. I imagine there is a much faster and more programmatic way of achieving my final JSON file, but I'm unsure as to what that is.

Comment: Why not simply use [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: Because serialising the `Person` class into JSON using JSON.NET will not give me the above structure.

Comment: That sounds completely unreliable. What if `Address` had a property with the same name as `Person`? -- Anyways, it will save you a lot of headache, if you have an actual data structure (classes) that matches the desired JSON structure *exacly*. -- then: map your current structure into the JSON-like structure and then serialize it from there to JSON string.

Comment: Just use LINQ to convert your persons list to a structure in your wanted format and then feed this into JSON.NET.

Comment: Automapper + Json.NET if you don't feel like writing your mapping by hand.

Comment: @Corak The possible descriptions for each PersonField element are pre-set, and therefore conflicts won't happen. The real problem is more complex than this, I just simplified it for clarity.

Comment: @ckuri Do you have an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: @JakeMangan Json.NET, like any serializer,  will transform any structure. You need to use LINQ to bring your objects to the structure you want.

Comment: @JakeMangan btw that's a rather bad JSON structure. Why use `Description/Value` fields in a JSON *dictionary*? Why not use `"Postcode":"AB1 2CD"`?

Answer (score 1):

First put all properties from the root class and the property classes in a single list. Each list item is an anonymous class with a field `Property` for the property and `Parent` for the parent property or null if `Property` is from the root class, i.e. for all properties from `Person` the `Parent` is null, for all properties from `Address` the parent is `HomeAddress`.

```
var rootProps = typeof(Person).GetProperties();
var flattenedProperties = new[] { new { Parent = (PropertyInfo)null, Properties = rootProps.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToArray() } }
    .Concat(rootProps.Where(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string) && p.PropertyType.IsClass).Select(p => new { Parent = p, Properties = p.PropertyType.GetProperties() } ))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Properties, (x, p) => new { x.Parent, Property = p })
    .ToArray();
```

Iterate through each person, read all property values, construct an anonymous object tree of the expected output structure and then feed this into JSON.NET.
I am assuming `persons` is a list of your `Person` objects.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
  People = persons.Select((x, i) => new
  {
    PersonId = (i + 1).ToString(),
    PersonFields = flattenedProperties.Select(p => new
    {
      Description = p.Property.Name,
      Value = p.Property.GetValue(p.Parent == null ? x : p.Parent.GetValue(x))
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects) to do what you want.  Load your array of people into a [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm), then transform it like this:

```
JArray array = JArray.FromObject(people);

JObject result = new JObject(
    new JProperty("People", 
        new JArray(array.Children<JObject>()
            .Select(jo => 
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("PersonId", jo["PersonId"]),
                    new JProperty("PersonFields", 
                        new JArray(jo.Descendants()
                            .OfType<JProperty>()
                            .Where(jp => jp.Name != "PersonId" && jp.Value is JValue)
                            .Select(jp => 
                                new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("Description", jp.Name),
                                    new JProperty("Value", jp.Value)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

string json = result.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R0Iajk