# Is there a less cumbersome way to generate large repetitive JSON files in C#?

Tags: c#, json

My end goal is to produce a JSON file that has the following structure

```
{
  "Info": [
    {
      "Detail1": "value1",
      "Detail2": "value2",
      "Detail3": "value3",
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Description": "Field1",
          "Value": "value4"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Field2",
          "Value": "value5"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Field3",
          "Value": "value6"
        }
        ,
        {
        ... continue for another 100~ fields
        },

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON file contains a number of header details, denoted by `Detail1`, `Detail2` and `Detail3`. It then contains an array `Fields` that contains around 100 separate elements, each field contains a unique description and value, all of which are known prior. The values for the `Fields` elements are stored in a separate class.

Please note that `Detail1` and `value1` etc are just placeholder names, the actual data being used is different.

At the moment the code I have to generate this JSON is extremely long, ugly and hardcoded and just isn't an elegant solution. I'd much rather replace the code with something else if there is any other solution available.

Here is the code I have at the moment

```
JObject result = new JObject(
                new JProperty("Info",
                    //new JObject(
                    new JArray(
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("Detail1", preJson.value1),
                            new JProperty("Detail2", preJson.value2),
                            new JProperty("Detail3", preJson.value3),
                            new JProperty("Fields",
                                new JArray(
                                    new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("Description", "Field1"),
                                        new JProperty("Value", preJson.Field1)),
                                    new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("Description", "Field2"),
                                        new JProperty("Value", preJson.Field2)),
                                    new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("Description", "Field3"),
                                        new JProperty("Value", preJson.Field3)),
                                    new JObject(
                                        ...continue for 100~ fields
                               )))))));
```

`preJson` is simply a DTO object that contains all of the information required within the JSON file and is used to organise the data before restructuring into JSON format.

The only solution to this I can think of is including the descriptions for each element within `Fields` within a text file or array and then somehow iterating through the array and extracting the details of each element in turn, instead of hard coding each individual element within a new JObject, but I am unsure whether this would even work.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but can't you just serialize you data model?

Comment: The values held within `Fields` are all stored within their own individual properties, and not in a `Fields` array within `preJson`, so serialisation would give me a flat JSON object, which isn't the structure I need. Edit: Even if I were to serialise, that would still require to populate `Fields` with all the elements needed, and so I'd still have the problem of long repetitive code.

Comment: This sounds like the [same question you asked a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53635953/10263).  Didn't either of those answers work for you?  How is this question different?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the classes for your model like:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string Detail1 { get; set; }
    public string Detail2 { get; set; }
    public string Detail3 { get; set; }
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Info> Info { get; set; }
}
```

Next populate the data and then assuming you are using Newtonsoft JSON.Net you can serialize the `RootObject` like:

```
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

Comment: Pretty much the exact answer I was about to give

Comment: Exact answer I was about to give too.

Comment: Pretty much the same answer everyone was about to give :D